# Extract data from a .Txt file and show it in a Queue and Stack in Java

Tags: java, stack, queue, txt

I need to read data from two .txt files and then sort its data as a queue or a stack. I know how to use queue and stacks but my problem is how I can open and use the data from the txt files.

Example

File1.txt = A B C

File2.txt = D E F

--Stack= C B A F E D
--Queue= A B C D E F

Comment: https://intellipaat.com/blog/tutorial/java-tutorial/java-file-io/ Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to read a file into a variable.

One way would be by making use of the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to read the content of a file line by line. Here is a small code example reading a file from the filesystem, and printing the content, line by line. You can use this and instead of printing the content, append it in your queue and stack.

```
try {
    File file1= new File("File1.txt");
    Scanner fileReader= new Scanner(file1);
    
    while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
        String fileLine= fileReader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(fileLine);
    }
    
    fileReader.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File could not be found.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BufferedReader

```
File file=new File("file1.txt");
BufferedReader  reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line="";
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
     // enqueue(line);
     //  push(line);
}
```

Do this for the Two files

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but it says : "Incompatible types: File cannot be converted to reader"

Comment: Use This ,or the edited one

File file=new File("file1.txt");
BufferedReader  reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line="";
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
     // enqueue(line);
     //  push(line);
}